# Value Error while calculating gradient using numpy.gradient

Tags: python, numpy

For calculating the divergence of ocean surface currents, I tried to use numpy.gradient( to calculate du/dy and dv/dx). My latitude and longitude are 2d arrays. So when I use the np.gradient method it gives ValueError: distances must be either scalars or 1d.

Then I reshaped the latitude and longitude to 1d array but still I got an error with message distance must be same.

```
dudx,dudy=np.gradient(U[0],x2,y2)
```

Where 'x2' is my longitude and 'y2' is my latitude and U is a 3d array U(time, latitude, longitude).

Comment: create minimal working code with some data so we could easily copy and run it.

Comment: How does `U` relate to `x` and `y`?  You can't just 'reshape` `x` and `y` and still maintain the relationship.  Read the `gradient` docs carefully, and if necessary play with the examples.  The function does not require 1d arrays just to be difficult.  You need to understand their purpose.